# $text $search in MongoDB on Large dataset taking very long to match

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a data set of ~31.3M documents in my Database in MongoDB. I need to search a particular string in properties of each document, if found in any property then that document is a match case.

Currently I have done text indexing on properties where I need to check the string and matching it by the following code

My main issue is the time complexity, it takes around 25-35 mins to run the above query, where I want the result in seconds/millisecond.

```
await collectionName.aggregate([{
        $match: {
            $text: {
                $search: uniqueActiveName
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $out: "tempCollectionName"
    }
]).toArray()
```

I am returning the result of the matched documents into a new collection so that I can do my further operations on the filtered result.

Please check my document structure here [sampleJSON](https://wollemisolutions-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/p/karanvirr_kumar/Eqdb3iyXaOJMumXeKTYfTV4BmqUu8u3iE_KdBOMBmKyDTg?e=StgRTN)

I have done text Indexing on the following properties

```
 await collectionName.createIndex({
        articleTitle: "text",
        "abstract.background": "text",
        "abstract.objective": "text",
        "abstract.method": "text",
        "abstract.results": "text",
        "abstract.conclusions": "text",
        "abstract.unassigned": "text",
        materialAndMethods: "text",
        acknowledgement: "text",
        conflictOfInterestOrDeclarationsOfInterest: "text",
        contributionsOfAuthorsOrContributions: "text",
        funding: "text",
    }, {
        default_language: "none",
        language_override: "none"
    })
```

Comment: What are the possible values of the `uniqueActiveName` variable? Said another way - are they full words? Can you provide some sample documents?

Comment: uniqueActiveName value will be eg. **"John Smith"**.
It will always include double quotes for an exact match of my matching string and type will always be string of the variable

Comment: @user20042973 Update the description of the issue and added a sample document.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this isn't really an answer, but this would be too long to leave as a comment.

Hoping to run a full text search across 12 fields on 30+ million documents with millisecond response times probably isn't reasonable (particularly if you're writing them to another collection).

It's a little hard to find benchmarks online for mongo full text search, but some numbers I saw suggested 800ms/100k documents, but didn't say what size the documents were, another suggested 10 minutes for a 44GB corpus, but again - not which portion of the data was being searched sadly.

There are a couple of things that are probably contributing to the slowness, and some things to think about.

1. your $out will write these to an actual collection, which depending on your mongo version and options might require acknowledgement from the majority of members that these have actually been written to disk - this is inherently extremely slow
2. your documents are quite large, writing all the fields of those documents to a new collection makes it even slower.
3. How much memory does your cluster have, and how large is the text index your trying to use?
4. Can you get metrics from your cluster while this query is running - how much time is spent in replication?
5. How many results do you get/expect to get on each of these?

In general, unless you *truly* need full text search (e.g., you require a score), it's better not to use it and stick to strict indexing. For example, you could (on your app server) concatenate all those fields together, split on whitespace, convert to lower case and de-duplicate, then store those values as an array and index that array. When searching you do the same operations to your query and use $in to find them - this gives you word level matching, you can take it a step further and use n-grams if you need more granularity.